# application removed from recent application list

Tags: android, interface, listener, applicationcontext

My query is, i want to **cancel services using alarm manager when application going to destroy/closed**.

if i am in activity **A** by clicking on button started activity **B** suddenly user is going to press home button. 
---- if application is running in background then **don't cancel service**. but **when he going to remove from recent list of application** at that time cancel service.

Service/Alarm manager will work even when user has sent application in background by pressing home screen.

**No of way application can closed**.

 1) By clicking back button (multiple times if stack have multiple activities).

2) By pressing home button and then remove from recent list.

i am **facing issue with (2)second option**. in that when user press home button at that time service or alarm manager should be work. But `when user will be going to remove application from recent list at that time i want to cancel service/alarm manager`.

**Is there any Listners/Methods through which we can identify?**

Comment: Are you looking for `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroy`?

Comment: Try override onDestrory()

Comment: no keyser. looking for LISTNER who talks me application going to destroy.

Comment: please check question i have edited.

Comment: please post another solution except accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever My service is going to execute at that i am now checking isAppRunning() if it returns true then execute Service Otherwise cancel the service, simple:)

```
public boolean isAppRunning(Context context)
        {
            boolean appFound = false;
            final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++)
            {
                if (recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.getPackageName().equals("mypackagename"))
                {
                    appFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return appFound;
        }
```

**Add Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

So whenever it is remove from recent list. i will know by this method.

Answer (score -1):

Add `onDestroy()` in your class

```
@Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         //do your code here
     }
```